# `kpfonts` light option

Tags: fonts, package-options, kpfonts

I am a bit confused by this sentence in the `kpfonts` package documentation:

> With the light option, the print is better than display!

May I understand that the `light` option produces a better result when printed if compared to the normal font, while the default font is better if reading the document from a screen?

If yes, is there any circumstance under which `light` option could render a different general layout (line breaks, boxes alignment...), so there are more differences than the appearance of the glyphs when switching to the default? (i.e., will my printed (`light`) and pdf (default) versions be consistent?)

Comment: Of course the printed version and the pdf version are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it only means that if you use `light` and are disappointed because it doesn't look good, you might want to look at the printed version because `light` looks worse on display than on paper.
A similar effect occurs with Latin Modern: Many people think that it looks much better on paper than on screen.

In both cases this is because these proper and consistent representation of light fonts needs small dots/pixels because features of the glyphs might otherwise be too small to be visible.
When glyph outlines are mapped to the pixel grid, you can often have some rounding effects where the actual thickness of glyph strokes have to be a whole number of pixels. If stroke widths of lighter fonts are not significantly bigger than the size of a pixel, this rounding can deform glyphs and lead to an uneven look. Another problem appears when strokes should actually be thinner than a single pixel. Depending on the system they might appear gray (because of antialiasing systems), disappear, or be forced to be at least one pixel wide.

So while it compares `light` on paper with `light` on screen, it does not compare `light` with the regular version.

If you prefer `light` or regular is a matter of personal taste. Personally I think lighter fonts look more elegant, but especially for small sizes they can be harder to read and as discussed above small sizes can lead to problems on displays.
So I would recommend that you try both version on paper and display and decide for yourself.

The `kpfonts` documentation states that `thin` and regular fonts have the same metrics, so line breaks, box alignments etc. will not change when switching between `light` and regular. This is a special property of `kpfonts` fonts, it is often not true for other font families.